# pandas: merge on column of collections.Counter (or even just dict) objects?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I need to perform a merge of two pandas DataFrames using columns with `collections.Counter` objects (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). The merge raises a weird error. See executable code example below.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
a = pd.DataFrame([(120000.0, 120000.0, 0.0, 120000.0),
 (120000.0, 280000.0, 120000.0, 120000.0),
 (280000.0, 280000.0, 120000.0, 280000.0),
 (280000.0, 420000.0, 280000.0, 280000.0),
 (420000.0, 420000.0, 280000.0, 420000.0),
 (420000.0, 500000.0, 420000.0, 420000.0),
 (500000.0, 580000.0, 420000.0, 500000.0),
 (580000.0, 820000.0, 500000.0, 580000.0),
 (820000.0, 860000.0, 580000.0, 820000.0),
 (860000.0, 1160000.0, 820000.0, 860000.0),
 (1160000.0, 1160000.0, 860000.0, 1160000.0)])
b = pd.DataFrame([(120000.0, 120000.0, 0.0, 120000.0),
 (120000.0, 280000.0, 120000.0, 120000.0),
 (280000.0, 280000.0, 120000.0, 280000.0),
 (280000.0, 440000.0, 280000.0, 280000.0),
 (440000.0, 440000.0, 280000.0, 440000.0),
 (440000.0, 520000.0, 440000.0, 440000.0),
 (520000.0, 580000.0, 440000.0, 520000.0),
 (580000.0, 820000.0, 520000.0, 580000.0),
 (820000.0, 860000.0, 580000.0, 820000.0),
 (860000.0, 1120000.0, 820000.0, 860000.0),
 (1120000.0, 1160000.0, 860000.0, 1120000.0)])
a['ID'] = [Counter(i) for i in list(a.values)]
b['ID'] = [Counter(i) for i in list(b.values)]
pd.merge(a, b, on='ID')
```

This returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 601, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 73, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/home/ilya/tmp/tmp_merge.py", line 33, in <module>
    pd.merge(a, b, on='ID')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 38, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 186, in get_result
    join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 273, in _get_join_info
    sort=self.sort, how=self.how)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 461, in _get_join_indexers
    llab, rlab, shape = map(list, zip( * map(fkeys, left_keys, right_keys)))
TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not itertools.imap
```

I tried converting Counter objects to normal dicts (i.e.

```
b['ID'] = [dict(Counter(i)) for i in list(b.values)]
```

), but it didn't help. Is this normal behaviour? If yes, how do I circumvent this error?  Or is there any other way to achieve the same end result?

I use python 2.7 and pandas 0.16.1 (and normally ipython notebook, but this was tested in just python as well).

EDIT:
To clarify what all this is for.
I need to merge based on values of two pairs of columns. In the real data they are Start1, End1, Start2, End2. End2>Start2, End1>Start1. The example is with a subset of my real values. The problem is that in two datasets may be a situation that (Start1_1, End1_1)==(Start2_2, End2_2) and (Start1_2, End1_2)==(Start2_1, End2_1); I want these lines to be merged as well (the second number denotes the dataset). I thought using such counters should be the easiest solution, and I am pretty sure there will be no false positives this way.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting an error trying to hash a dict?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know...

Comment: what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of getting around this is to create a column (for each DataFrame) of a version of your original data structure converted to a hashable type.

E.g.,

```
a['IDHash'] = a.ID.apply(lambda r: tuple(sorted(r.iteritems())))
b['IDHash'] = b.ID.apply(lambda r: tuple(sorted(r.iteritems())))
```

and then

```
pd.merge(a, b, on='IDHash')
```

After that, just erase the columns.