# pandas: merge on column of ByteArray

Tags: python, merge, arrays, teradata

Any ideas on how I can join two pandas arrays on a commonly named bytearray field?  The field in the source (Teradata) is an actual ByteArray, and from the Teradata Side, this cannot be forced to character or something usable outside of Teradata)

The Teradata Export reads into a Panda's array beautifully. But I can't merge two tables with a commonly named field (DatabaseId) where that field is a bytearray.

(importing both pandas as pd and itertools)

When I try a simple merge of:

```
merge1 = pd.merge(tvm, dbase, on="DatabaseId")
```

I get the error of:

```
TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not itertools.imap
```

I searched StackOverflow and found a [similar problem for joining on a cell containing a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166814/pandas-merge-on-column-of-collections-counter-or-even-just-dict-objects)

```
dbase['DBID'] = dbase.DatabaseId.apply(lambda r: type(sorted(r.iteritems())))
```

But I get the Error:

```
AttributeError: 'bytearray' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

***UPDATE***

Example of Data
Data gathered through pandas using

```
dbase = pd.read_sql('select databaseid, databasename from ud812.dbase sample 10', conn)
conn is a connection to a teradata database
```

Data Types coming out of Teradata are Varchar for all columns EXCEPT:

```
DatabaseID = bytearray (Byte(4))
TVMID = bytearray (Byte(4))

>>> dbase.dtypes
DatabaseId      object
DatabaseName    object
dtype: object
>>> dbase
         DatabaseId         DatabaseName
0  [2, 0, 243, 185]  PCDW_CRS_BBCONV3_TB
1  [2, 0, 168, 114]            PAMLIF_TB
2  [2, 0, 133, 153]        PADW_PRESN_TB
3   [2, 0, 29, 184]       CEDW_MOBILE_TB
4  [2, 0, 190, 183]  CEDW_MODEL_SCORE_TB
5    [2, 0, 71, 55]            PBBBAM_TB
6  [2, 0, 169, 183]          CEDW_OCC_TB
7  [2, 0, 201, 183]    CCDW_DGTL_DEAL_TB
8    [0, 0, 139, 8]           PRECDSS_TB
9  [2, 0, 142, 203]             CDBDW_TB
>>>
>>>
>>> tvm.dtypes
TVMId         object
DatabaseId    object
TVMName       object
TableKind     object
CreateText    object
dtype: object
>>> tvm
                      TVMId        DatabaseId                        TVMName  \
0    [230, 1, 41, 11, 0, 0]   [2, 0, 67, 183]               JCP_03538_112002
1   [214, 1, 60, 133, 0, 0]   [2, 0, 186, 52]        STL_AUTHNCTD_RULE_EXECN
2    [193, 2, 59, 48, 0, 0]  [2, 0, 225, 150]       uye177_Xsell_EM_OPCL_TB2
3    [0, 2, 235, 154, 0, 0]  [2, 0, 244, 181]  PL_CALCD_INVSTR_MTHLY_HIST_ST
4   [255, 1, 131, 76, 0, 0]   [2, 0, 110, 63]            IMH867_AVA0803_SNAP
5  [125, 1, 217, 138, 0, 0]  [2, 0, 237, 153]            FD_ACCT_STMT_ADR_ST
6   [224, 0, 80, 233, 0, 0]  [2, 0, 243, 127]             EXP_SRCH_RSLT_DESC
7    [208, 1, 72, 15, 0, 0]     [2, 0, 8, 57]      SGI_PAY_DENIED_SEP_112012
8    [246, 0, 27, 61, 0, 0]  [2, 0, 143, 130]                      CR_INDIVD
9  [186, 1, 242, 167, 0, 0]   [0, 0, 244, 18]                 wzu448_sb_apps

  TableKind                                         CreateText
0         T                                               None
1         V  CREATE VIEW  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2         T                                               None
3         V  CREATE VIEW  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
4         T                                               None
5         V  CREATE VIEW  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
6         V  CREATE VIEW  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
7         V  CREATE VIEW  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
8         V  CREATE VIEW  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
9         T                                               None
```

Comment: What is the type of `tvm`? Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: Well, you can convert BYTEs to a string using the FROM_BYTES function. It's ugly syntax because you have to use LPAD (leading zeroes are ignored) and TRANSLATE (result is in Unicode) and  a CAST (LPAD returns a VARCHAR(32000): `CAST(TRANSLATE(LPAD(FROM_BYTES(tvmid, 'Base16'),12,'0') USING unicode_to_latin) AS VARCHAR(12))
` ( **12** is twice the number of bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your `bytearray`s to their immutable cousin `bytes`.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create your example `dbase`
DatabaseId_dbase = list(map(bytearray, [[2, 0, 243, 185], [2, 0, 168, 114],
    [2, 0, 133, 153], [2, 0, 29, 184], [2, 0, 190, 183], [2, 0, 71, 55],
    [2, 0, 169, 183], [2, 0, 201, 183], [0, 0, 139, 8], [2, 0, 142, 203]]))
DatabaseName = ['PCDW_CRS_BBCONV3_TB', 'PAMLIF_TB', 'PADW_PRESN_TB',
    'CEDW_MOBILE_TB', 'CEDW_MODEL_SCORE_TB', 'PBBBAM_TB', 'CEDW_OCC_TB',
    'CCDW_DGTL_DEAL_TB', 'PRECDSS_TB', 'CDBDW_TB']
dbase = pd.DataFrame({'DatabaseId': DatabaseId_dbase,
                      'DatabaseName': DatabaseName})

# Create your example `tvm`
DatabaseId_tvm = list(map(bytearray, [[2, 0, 67, 183], [2, 0, 186, 52],
    [2, 0, 225, 150], [2, 0, 244, 181], [2, 0, 110, 63], [2, 0, 237, 153],
    [2, 0, 243, 127], [2, 0, 243, 185], [2, 0, 143, 130], [0, 0, 244, 18]]))
TVMId = list(map(bytearray, [[230, 1, 41, 11, 0, 0], [214, 1, 60, 133, 0, 0],
    [193, 2, 59, 48, 0, 0], [0, 2, 235, 154, 0, 0], [255, 1, 131, 76, 0, 0],
    [125, 1, 217, 138, 0, 0], [224, 0, 80, 233, 0, 0], [208, 1, 72, 15, 0, 0],
    [246, 0, 27, 61, 0, 0], [186, 1, 242, 167, 0, 0]]))
TVMName = ['JCP_03538_112002', 'STL_AUTHNCTD_RULE_EXECN',
    'uye177_Xsell_EM_OPCL_TB2', 'PL_CALCD_INVSTR_MTHLY_HIST_ST',
    'IMH867_AVA0803_SNAP', 'FD_ACCT_STMT_ADR_ST', 'EXP_SRCH_RSLT_DESC',
    'SGI_PAY_DENIED_SEP_112012', 'CR_INDIVD', 'wzu448_sb_apps']
TableKind = ['T', 'V', 'T', 'V', 'T', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'T']
tvm = pd.DataFrame({'DatabaseId': DatabaseId_tvm, 'TVMId': TVMId,
                    'TVMName': TVMName, 'TableKind': TableKind})

# This line would fail with the following error
#     TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not map
# merge = pd.merge(tvm, dbase, on='DatabaseId')

# Apply the `bytes` constructor to the `bytearray` columns    
dbase['DatabaseId'] = dbase['DatabaseId'].apply(bytes)
tvm['DatabaseId'] = tvm['DatabaseId'].apply(bytes)
tvm['TVMId'] = tvm['TVMId'].apply(bytes)

# Now it works!
merge = pd.merge(tvm, dbase, on='DatabaseId')
```

The resulting `merge` is

```
   DatabaseId                     TVMId                    TVMName  \
0  b'\x02\x00\xf3\xb9'  b'\xd0\x01H\x0f\x00\x00'  SGI_PAY_DENIED_SEP_112012   

  TableKind         DatabaseName  
0         V  PCDW_CRS_BBCONV3_TB
```

(I had to change the `DatabaseId` field of one of the rows in your `tvm`, since otherwise `merge` would have been empty. I also didn't include the `CreateText` column — too awkward for SO)

Comment: Worked Beautifully Thank you!