# Storing all values when creating a Pandas Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Basically, I'm aggregating prices over three indices to determine: mean, std, as well as an upper/lower limit. So far so good. However, now I want to also find the lowest identified price which is still >= the computed lower limit.

My first idea was to use np.min to find the lowest price -> this obviously disregards the lower-limit and is not useful. Now I'm trying to store all the values the pivot table identified to find the price which still is >= lower-limit. Any ideas?

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(temp, index=['A','B','C'],values=['price'], aggfunc=[np.mean,np.std],fill_value=0)

pivot['lower_limit'] = pivot['mean'] - 2 * pivot['std']
pivot['upper_limit'] = pivot['mean'] + 2 * pivot['std']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, merge `pivoted[lower_limit]` back into `temp`. Thus, for each `price` in `temp` there is also a `lower_limit` value.

```
temp = pd.merge(temp, pivoted['lower_limit'].reset_index(), on=ABC)
```

Then you can restrict your attention to those rows in `temp` for which the `price` is >= `lower_limit`:

```
temp.loc[temp['price'] >= temp['lower_limit']]
```

The desired result can be found by computing a `groupby/min`:

```
result = temp.loc[temp['price'] >= temp['lower_limit']].groupby(ABC)['price'].min()
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2017)
N = 1000
ABC = list('ABC')
temp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(N,3)), columns=ABC)
temp['price'] = np.random.random(N)
pivoted = pd.pivot_table(temp, index=['A','B','C'],values=['price'], 
                         aggfunc=[np.mean,np.std],fill_value=0)
pivoted['lower_limit'] = pivoted['mean'] - 2 * pivoted['std']
pivoted['upper_limit'] = pivoted['mean'] + 2 * pivoted['std']

temp = pd.merge(temp, pivoted['lower_limit'].reset_index(), on=ABC)
result = temp.loc[temp['price'] >= temp['lower_limit']].groupby(ABC)['price'].min()
print(result)
```

yields

```
A  B  C
0  0  0    0.003628
      1    0.000132
   1  0    0.005833
      1    0.000159
1  0  0    0.006203
      1    0.000536
   1  0    0.001745
      1    0.025713
```

Comment: Amazing! This seems to work exactly how I want it to for your example - not for mine though. I'm getting following error: `type object argument after * must be an iterable, not itertools.imap`  Might be as the values in A, B, C are date objects?

Comment: Date objects in `A`,`B`,`C` won't cause this problem, but some iterables might. (See https://stackoverflow.com/q/31166814/190597.) If that does not seem similar to your situation, please post `temp.head().reset_index().to_dict('list')`. This will show us an unambiguous representation of the first few rows of `temp`. If we are lucky, it will allow us to reproduce the error you are seeing.

Comment: I was wrong -- the example you posted reproduces the error with non-iterable
values in `A`, `B` and `C`.  I'm speculating that the error occurs because the
dtype of temp's `A` column is `datetime64[ns, UTC]` while `pivoted`'s `A` index
level is a `DatetimeIndex`. Regardless, there is a simple fix: instead of using
`pivoted['lower_limit'].to_frame()` use
`pivoted['lower_limit'].reset_index()`. I've edited the code above to show what I mean.
`reset_index` will move the `A`, `B`, `C` index levels back into columns. Thus the merge operation will be between
identical dtypes.

Comment: This is brilliant and it worked. I know I'm not supposed to comment "thanks" but: thanks a lot!!